# Design of circuit to reduce flickering of LED

Tags: led

I want to Design a circuit to reduce flickering of LED(1.6 v) powered by a DC motor acting as a generator .Mechanical input is kinetic energy of water.Plz suggest me a circuit .What if we employ two condensers,one will charged for sometime and then it will be discharged through a 1 watt LED and the other being charged simultaneosly when the LED is getting discharged.Voltage generated at the end of LED is 1.6volts.

Comment: You want to design a circuit yet you are asking for a circuit? You probably will need to use a diode.

Comment: The output of the generator is a Sine wave?  What sort of  voltage?  And you are sending that directly across the LED?  (with some resistance?)  You could make a full wave rectifier with a diode bridge, but that will eat up ~1.2V.  Or perhaps you have mechanical rectifiers on the generator?    (OK clearly you need to provide more information.)

Comment: Do you have any specifications for the motor and the LED? Can you draw some kind of sketch to show what you were thinking about doing with the condensors? Is there anything else being powered by this circuit, or only the LED? If there is something else, please provide details (how much power / voltage and nature of the load).

Comment: Your motor rating (in volts) will need to be greater than the worst case forward voltage for the LED or else it will add to the flickering.

Answer (score 1):

Using a condenser (more often called a capacitor these days) is a good way to filter out flicker (noise) in power coming from a DC generator.  The capacitor would be placed across the two output wires of the generator, (likely after a fuse or other protection device).  Be sure to follow the designated polarity of the capacitor.

After the capacitor you have your current limiting component (often a resistor) then the LED.

The capacitance value and voltage rating of the capacitor depends on the maximum output of your generator.  The higher the capacitance value the more filtering. A generator powered by a unpredictable power source might give a very wide range of output so be sure to select a capacitor with a high enough voltage ratings to give yourself the best protection from damage.

Comment: You have to use a diode before the capacitor otherwise it will just discharge instantly through the generator and there is no benefit in adding a capacitor (no energy buffering). Depending on the output voltage of the generator, this might make the system inefficient.

Comment: A diode in line ahead of the capacitor may help, though this depends on the type of rotor contacts within the "DC" motor.

Comment: I was going to say that depending on the physics involved, the big jump in mechanical resistance when the LED starts to conduct may automatically limit the power input and so an electrical resistor may not be needed in that specific case...But a capacitor couldn't continue that for more than a few milliseconds (voltage would drop below threshold), and the alternate solution of an inductor would be prohibitively unwieldy and require two diodes instead of one.  So Nedd's solution is probably the best.